# I would like to make the drop down menu and the mobile menu transparent , I use a theme called simple

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using a theme for my wordpress website called simple ,I created a main_navigation which first links to a page and then it has sub menu elements which link to the individual parts of the static page.
All these parts of the menu are in perfect shape they link to the corresponding page and everything works fine.The problem i am facing is when i try to change the drop down menu's background and mobile menu's background transparent.

so i used the main word press customizing option to change these menu to transparent and even tried hard code the css , but they did not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "they didn't work"? Can you share any CSS that you have tried already?

Comment: Can you share the CSS that you have used and where have you added this CSS?

Comment: this is the css i tried for the drop down `.main-navigation ul.menu ul.sub-menu {background:transparent}` i put the above code in the custom css area of the WordPress customization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is an issue with the theme simple , so to achieve transparent drop down only the values in the wordpress main customization should be tinkered with.